# Populating a Bootstrap dropdown from an MS SQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I've been racking my brains all morning, and I have searched on loads of pages via Google.

I can't find a way to populate a bootstrap button dropdown box with data from a MS SQL server.

Plenty of ways to do a plain HTML dropdown from MySQL.

This is the code of the button:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Family</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 3</a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to fetch the data from the db? Can you try populating it with an array for testing?

Comment: Yeah I can get the data from the db, I'm currently using it to populate a table.

Comment: Great! You should be able to use a loop to populate the dropdown. If the dropdown is for a form and you plan to submit the values, you may need to specify it the question as well. Is that so?

Comment: I removed the `sql-server` tag, because the accepted answer uses `mysqli` PHP extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly populate a dropdown from MySQL using HTML, for that you will need to use PHP, so you can access your database server-side, if you want to populate your dropdown item from your MySQL database.

So you need to turn your HTML file to a PHP file (index.html -> index.php) and inside that you need to have something like that:

**index.php**

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Family</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php
            // server credentials
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "username";
            $password = "password";
            $dbname = "myDB";

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }

            // Replace with the desired SQL
            $sql = "SELECT options FROM MyOptions";
            
            // get the results
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
            {
                // output data of each row
                while($option = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                {
                    // change "name" to the column fo your DB row.  
                    echo "<a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>".$option["name"]."</a> ";

                    // if you also store a link to your DB, for ex in a column link then use
                    // echo "<a class='dropdown-item' href='".option["link"]."'>".$option["name"]."</a> ";
                }
            } 
            $conn->close();
        ?>
     </div>
 </div>
```